# Science paper information extraction with Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, text, web-scraping, text-mining

I am just new to Python and it just happens to me that I need to extraction some information from a few science papers.

If given something plain text like:

1. **Introduction**
   some long writings
2. **Methodology**
   some long writings
3. **Results**
   some long writings

How could I put one paper into a dictionary like the follow?

```
paper_1 = {
           'Introduction': some long writings,
           'Methodology': some long writings,
           'Results': some long writings
          }
```

So many thanks :-)

---

After trying, I got some code running but it does not work perfectly:

```
text = 'introduction This is the FIRST part.' \
       'Methodologies This is the SECOND part.' \
       'results This is the THIRD part.'

import re
from re import finditer

d={}
first =[]
second =[]
title_list=[]
all =[]

for match in finditer("Methodology|results|methodologies|introduction|", text, re.IGNORECASE):
    if match.group() is not '':
        title = match.group()
        location = match.span()
        first.append(location[0])
        second.append(location[1])
        title_list.append(title)

all.append(first)
all.append(second)

a=[]
for i in range(2):
    j = i+1
    section = text[all[1][i]:all[0][j]]
    a.append(section)

for i in zip(title_list, a):
    d[i[0]] = i[1]
print (d)
```

This would give the following results:

```
{
'introduction': ' This is the FIRST part.', 
'Methodologies': ' This is the SECOND part.'
}
```

However,

i) it is not able to extract the last bit, which is the RESULTS part.

ii). In the loop, I gave the range() function an input of 2 because I know there are only 3 sections(introduction, methodology and results) but in some papers, people would add more sections, how could I automatically assign the correct value to range()? For example some papers may have the following sections:

1. **Introduction**
   some long writings
2. **General background about something**
   some long writings
3. **some sort of section title**
   some long writings
4. **Methodology**
   some long writings
5. **Results**
   some long writings

iii). Is there a more efficient way that I could build the dictionary in each loop? So I do not need to use the second loop.

---

30-03-2018 update:

Code updated as follow:

```
def section_detection(text):
    title_list=[]
    all =[[],[]]
    dic={}
    count = 0
    pattern = '\d\. [A-Z][a-z]*'

    for match in finditer(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
        if match.group() is not '':
            all[0].append(match.span()[0])
            all[1].append(match.span()[1])
            title_list.append(match.group())
            count += 1

    for i in range(count):
        j = i+1
        try:
            dic[title_list[i]]=text[all[1][i]:all[0][j]]
        except IndexError:
            dic[title_list[i]]=text[all[1][i]:]

    return dic
```

if executed as follow:

```
import re
from re import finditer
text = '1. introduction This is the FIRST part.' \
       '2. Methodologies This is the SECOND part.' \
       '3. results This is the THIRD part.'\
       '4. somesection This SOME section'

dic = section_detection(text)
print(dic)
```

Gives:

```
{'1. introduction': ' This is the FIRST part.', '2. Methodologies': ' This is the SECOND part.', '3. results': ' This is the THIRD part.', '4. somesection': ' This SOME section'}
```

Many thanks for all of you! :-)

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem: start coding. If you hit a snag, come back with your code and we might be able to help. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots - we can NOT copy and paste those to fix your code.

Comment: Hi Patrick, many thanks for you advice, and I have the code uploaded.

Comment: This is called [tag:scraping] - look for questions and articles about that. Come back when you have a specific coding question. Also, arxiv.org is probably a good startpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really liked the regex written by @Franz Forstmayr. Just want to point out some way to break it though.

```
text = '''
introduction This is the FIRST part.
introductionMethodologies This is the SECOND part.
results This is the THIRD part.
'''

import re
#### Regex based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49546458/8083313
kw = ['methodology', 'results', 'methodologies', 'introduction']
pat = re.compile(r'(%s)' % '|'.join(kw), re.IGNORECASE)

sp = [x for x  in re.split(pat, text) if x]
print sp
dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(sp[0::2],sp[1::2])}

print(dic)


# {'\n': 'introduction',
#  'Methodologies': ' This is the SECOND part.\n',
#  ' This is the FIRST part.\n': 'introduction', 
#  'results': ' This is the THIRD part.\n'}
```

You can see that the list is shifted due to the \n character and the dictionary is broken. Hence I would suggest to place a hard slicing

```
out = re.split(pat, text)
lead = out[0:1]; ### Keep the lead available in case needed
sp = out[1:]

print sp
dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(sp[0::2],sp[1::2])}

print(dic)

# {'introduction': '',
#  'Methodologies': ' This is the SECOND part.\n',
#  'results': ' This is the THIRD part.\n'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
text = 'introduction This is the FIRST part. ' \
       'Methodologies This is the SECOND part. ' \
       'results This is the THIRD part. ' \

import re

kw = ['methodology', 'results', 'methodologies', 'introduction']

pat = re.compile(r'(%s)' % '|'.join(kw), re.IGNORECASE)

sp = [x for x  in re.split(pat, text) if x]
dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(sp[0::2],sp[1::2])}

print(dic)
```

But this is only for your example, don't except too much, in real world documents. You haven't specified, whats about the text before "Introduction", and whats about someone mentioning "result" in plain text?

Comment: It's quite funny that you just imported `finditer` and let it sit there...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I started from the above example. Removed it :)